# Smooth frames and orientation

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

In Tu's "An Introduction to Manifolds", exercise 16.8, we are supposed to prove that $M$ has a trivial tangent bundle $\Leftrightarrow$ M admits a smooth frame $\{X_1, \dots, X_n\}$ (i.e., smooth vector fields $X_1, \dots, X_n$ such that $\{X_{1_p}, \dots, X_{n_p}\}$ is a basis for $T_pM$ for every $p\in M$).

When I read this, I concluded that $M$ is orientable $\Rightarrow$ M admits a smooth frame $\{X_1, \dots, X_n\}$ $\Rightarrow M$ has trivial tangent bundle. However, I've learned that $\mathbb{S}^2$ is an orientable manifold which has no trivial tangent bundle.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If $M$ has trivial tangent bundle, then $M$ is orientable. The converse is not true as your example demonstrates.

Comment: How do you read that orientable implies parallelizable(existence of global frame?

Comment: @melomm if $M$ is orientable, then there are smooth vector fields which form an oriented base for the tangent spaces, no? Wouldn't that be a smooth frame?

Comment: @rentatodias no globally. The counter example is $S^{2}$.

Comment: What definition of orientabiliy you are using?

Comment: The definition I'm thinking is this one: an orientation of $M$ is a set of smooth vector fields $X_1,...,X_n$ such that $\{X_{1_p},...,X_{n_p}\}$ is a basis for $T_pM$ for all $p$. So each $X_i$ must be defined on the whole $M$ and each must be smooth. What do you mean by "not globaly"? You mean $X_1,...,X_n$ must only be defined localy?

Comment: This is not a definition of orientability, this is the definition of parallelizable manifold https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold. 

The orientability has many definitions, but you can use this one:
Definition: A smooth manifold $M$ is orientable if there is an atlas $\{U_\alpha, \varphi_{\alpha}\}$ such that the change of coordinates $\varphi_{\alpha}\circ\varphi_{\beta}$ has positive Jacabian $(det(D(\varphi_{\alpha}\circ\varphi_{\beta})$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability

Comment: Yes, not globaly for me means that you don't have any guarantee that on a orientable manifold you can find this frame defined on the whole manifold.

Comment: I'm familiar with the definition using an oriented atlas, that one is clear to me. But there is this other one involving vector fields, right? That's the one I'm trying to get clear...

Comment: The @Andreas Cap's answer is the definition of orientability in terms of local vector fields. But I think so you are confuse because for an hypersurface $S$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ the orientability is equivalent to esistence a global _nornmal_ vector field, in particular the normal bundle is trivial. (The same is true if you change $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ by an orientable manifold )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am referring to your discussion with @melomm in the comments to the question. The right definition of orientability involving vector fields is the following. You have to specify an orientation of the tangent space $T_xM$ for all $x\in M$, which are compatible in the sense that for each $x\in M$, there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $x\in M$ and there are local vector fields $X_1,\dots X_n\in\mathfrak X(U)$ such that for each $y\in U$ the values $X_1(y),\dots,X_n(y)$ define a positively oriented basis for $T_yM$. Of course, this implies that $TM$ is trivial over $U$, but $TM$ is locally trivial anyway.

To see that this is equivalent to the definition via oriented atlasses roughly goes as follows. It easily follows from the defintions that for a connected local chart $(U_\alpha,\phi_\alpha)$ the choice of an orientation of $T_xM$ for one $x\in U_\alpha$ gives rise to a compatible choice for all $y\in U_\alpha$. If you have an oriented atlas than you can extend this orientation to all points in $M$. Conversely, if you have compatible orientations the charts inducing this given orientation form an oriented atlas.

Comment: that's a much better explanation then the ones I've found in textbooks, thanks!